# « Pousse mais pousse égal » : qu'est-ce qu'on pousse, égal comment, où et depuis quand ?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, québec, régionalismes, origine-ou-raison

Il y a une expression qui m'est connue à l'oral familier en français du Québec et que quelqu'un a identifiée dans le dictionnaire [*La Parlure*](http://www.laparlure.com/terme/pousse-mais-pousse-egal/) :

> [Pousse](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pousser) mais pousse [égal](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9gal).

L'entrée mentionne essentiellement que c'est employé pour *demander à quelqu'un de ne pas exagérer*. Personnellement je l'entends comme un *appel à la cohérence*, un peu dans la même veine. C'est souvent une réaction à ce que quelqu'un vient de dire, en particulier à mon avis quand ça diffère en substance et de manière marquée de ce qu'elle a exprimé précédemment, mais je peux me tromper, d'où la question. Et l'image me fait penser à la menuiserie, à l'emploi du rabot ou je ne sais trop quoi, cette idée d'égal, uni, plat, de la surface sans variation, avec l'emploi de l'adjectif vraisemblablement comme d'un [adverbe](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9galement).

Plus généralement, on ne s'étonnera guère de la richesse des sens de l'adjectif *égal*, qu'on l'on réfère à la qualité ou à la valeur, à la quantité ou à la dimension, au développement sans variation, aux avantages entre des individus, à la comparaison avec autrefois, ou à l'impartialité, voire à l'indifférence etc, l'*égal* s'y trouve. Quant au verbe *pousser*, [usuellement](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pousser/63173?q=pousser#62464) *exercer une pression*, qui a supplanté tardivement le verbe [*bouter*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bouter), il dispose de sens plus abstraits dont celui attesté chez Montaigne en 1581 pour « mener un comportement ou une situation jusqu'à ses dernières conséquences », sens sur lequel repose, par exemple, l'expression du 17<sup>e</sup> *pousser (qqn.) à bout* (DHLF/Rey). Il a aussi pu vouloir dire [*presser/haranguer*](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf) (*Glossaire du parler français au Canada*, éd. L'action sociale, 1930).

---

- Peut-on préciser le **sens** de l'expression et l'étayer avec un ou des exemples ou références (dictionnaires, dialogues etc.)?
- Peut-on identifier de quel sens du verbe *pousser* et de quel sens de l'adjectif *égal* procède l'expression, et préciser si l'emploi de cet adjectif à la manière d'un adverbe y change quoi que ce soit ?
- A-t-on des détails supplémentaires sur l'**origine** précise de la locution, est-elle uniformément reconnue au Québec ou associée à l'une de ses régions en particulier, est-ce une variante de *lever égal* (*à la même hauteur, également* ; ça m'est inconnu) et comment ?

Comment: Ce sens de _pousser_ serait-il à rapprocher de celui que Richard Desjardins utilise avant d'aller coucher dans son char?  «Tu t' rappelles, ton gros kick, / La belle Rose-Aimée? / **M'as t'en pousser une comique:** / Moi pis elle, c'est steady.»

Answer (score 5):

1. L'expression s'emploie pour dire "faut pas exagérer" (cf. *faut pas pousser*). Parfois avec une nuance de "soyez conséquents/logiques dans vos actions". Pour moi (j'ai 32 ans) elle est un peu datée. Ça me semble (impression totalement personnelle!) une expression de la génération de mon père, pas de la mienne.

   Le meilleur dictionnaire à consulter serait probablement [Usito](https://www.usito.com/) (Mon Dictionnaire Québécois d'Aujourd’hui se contente de mentionner l'expression sans la définir).

> J’allais acheter cette maison, mais quand j’ai vu le compte de taxes municipal annuel, là, j’ai dit wô les moteurs, [pousse, mais pousse égal](http://blogues.lapresse.ca/lagace/2009/05/30/jallais-acheter-cette-maison-mais/).
>
> Un politicien qui devient président des États-Unis à force de magouilles, de trahisons et de jeux de coulisses, passe encore. Mais en balançant une journaliste devant un wagon de métro ? [Pousse, mais pousse égal](http://plus.lapresse.ca/screens/496edbcc-5b1f-4315-bee9-9bbde4d6c664%7C_0.html), comme dirait ma mère.

2. Je suis pas mal sûr que c'est le sens de base, au même titre que dans l'expression mentionnée plus haut *faut pas pousser*.
3. L'étymologie ce n'est pas du tout mon rayon, j'en ai peur (de manière générale l'étymologie est peu avancée pour les expressions québécoises, déjà avec juste les mots...).

Answer (score 4):

Je démarre avec l’idée déjà énoncée que ***Pousse mais pousse égal*** est en effet une invitation à cesser l’exagération grossière, une mise-en-garde à son interlocuteur que l’on est en train de cesser complètement d’accorder du crédit à l’information qu’il transmet. Je tenterai d’en évaluerai les termes à la lumière de cette définition.

---

**POUSSER:** [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pousser), [Académie 8](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/pousser), [Académie 9](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/pousser)

Quelques utilisations de ce terme semblent pointer dans la direction générale du sens à donner à l’expression. Ainsi, ***pousser le bouchon (trop loin)***, image tirée du [jeu du bouchon](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bouchon), signifie exagérer, aller trop loin dans ses propos.

Nous avons aussi ***il ne faut pas pousser grand'mère dans les orties***, qui comporte aussi son jugement sur des mesures considérées trop extrêmes; nous sommes toujours dans le débordement.

Encore dans l’excès, on peut **pousser une attitude**, à priori positive, jusqu’au point où le comportement est perçu comme anormal et sa nature même en devient changée *(pousser le respect jusqu’à la flagornerie, l’amour jusqu’à l’aveuglement, l’économie jusqu’à l’avarice)*, ou **pousser un raisonnement jusqu’à l’absurde**, méthode employée avec profit en mathématiques dans l’art de la démonstration, mais qui montre rapidement ses limites dans l’univers humain, la vaste littérature disponible sur les [sophismes](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sophisme) en est un témoignage éloquent.

On peut aussi penser à ***pousser dans une direction*** ou ***vers une destination***, expressions qui incluent une idée de mouvement physique, mais qui se transfèrent aisément dans la dimension intellectuelle: n’explore-t-on pas le monde des idées comme nous explorons notre environnement? Et sans le pousser jusqu’à l’absurde, on peut tout de même pousser un raisonnement au-delà des limites déjà explorées. Par exemple, Einstein et ceux qui l’ont suivi ont étudié la relativité et cherché à comprendre la nature des conséquences qu’elle impliquait, ce qui a mené à des résultats incroyables, parfois si étranges qu’ils ne furent pas crus pas ceux mêmes qui les découvraient, mais qui furent pourtant confirmés plus tard. On pourra penser au dernier en date, d’actualité récente, l’observation d’ondes gravitationnelles.

Finalement, je mentionne l’utilisation qu’en fit Richard Desjardins dans sa chanson *«Et j’ai couché dans mon char»*:

> Tu t’rappelles, ton gros kick,
>   La belle Rose-Aimée?
>   **M’as t’en pousser une comique:**
>   Moi pis elle, c'est steady.

Il y a là l’idée de pousser une information vers l’interlocuteur, donc un mouvement de l’information vers un endroit où elle n’était pas encore parvenue. L’attestation ici présentée est certes postérieure à l’expression analysée, mais illustre bien une certaine compréhension du terme, bien vivante aujourd’hui, et possiblement liée elle aussi dans l’idée du transport d’information.

On peut donc estimer que l’utilisation du mot *pousser* ici s’inclue assez bien dans la nébuleuse des acceptions possibles du terme. Découle-t-elle d’une seule d’entre elle? Je ne saurais l’affirmer. Les nouvelles expressions qui surgissent spontanément sont souvent le produit d’un certain ensemble de notions liées aux mots qu’elles contiennent, et s’insèrent parfois dans un flou qui semble lier deux ou plusieurs acceptions. Si l’on n’a pas de première attestation connue (et je n’ai pas mis le doigt dessus), il est difficile d’envisager le contexte linguistique exact des gens qui ont inventé l’expression.

---

***ÉGAL* est-il utilisé adverbialement?**

À ceci une seule réponse possible: oui. À quel nom pourrait-il autrement se rapporter s’il était adjectif?

Je n’ai pas trouvé d’autres exemples de ce mot en particulier, mais il y a au moins ***soudain*** dont l’usage adverbial est reconnu de tous les dictionnaires et grammaires, et qui vit à peu près **correct** aux côtés de *soudainement*.

Dans l’argot parisien, l’utilisation de l’adjectif au lieu de l’adverbe habituel en *-ment* est courant. *Le bon usage, 14e édition* §963e cite entre autres Boudard:

> Je me prends *machinal* au jeu.

Un peu plus loin, Marcel Aymé est cité comme exemple hors-Paris, une répartie bien intéressante par sa juxtaposition d’un adverbe dérivé d’adjectif et d’un autre de construction plus habituelle:

> Je parle *direct* et j’agis franchement.

Ces exemples ne sont pas québécois et donc un peu à côté du propos, mais ils indiquent bien que le procédé d’utilisation d’un adjectif en adverbe est un processus avéré en français. ***Pousse mais pousse égal*** est d’ailleurs aussi citée, au même endroit, remarque 16.

Je ne vois pas comment le terme pourrait être adjectif, et donc je ne saurais discuter du changement que sa nature adverbiale provoque. On pourrait à la limite gloser: *Pousse mais pousse de manière à conserver les choses égales*, mais une expression aussi emberlificotée n’aurait jamais eu le succès de l’originale, et nous ne serions pas en train d’en discuter en ce moment.

---

**Une manière, parmi d’autres, de dériver l’expression d’une situation réelle**

Je donne ici une conception personnelle de l’expression. Elle n’est pas construite sur le néant, mais ne supporterait peut-être pas une analyse très poussée. Je m’excuse si j’ai présomptueusement présumé de sa valeur.

Tous ont probablement [déplacé ou vu déplacé un gros meuble dans un corridor étroit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXfKWIZQIo4). Les manœuvres à accomplir sont délicates, car la masse du meuble provoque le graffignage des murs à la moindre incartade et le maintien même du meuble est parfois difficile à cause de sa masse. Il faut aussi parfois effectuer différentes rotations selon plusieurs axes pour tourner convenablement les coins. Un ordre de pousser égal, au propre, peut très bien survenir lorsque deux personnes (de part et d’autre du meuble) se prêtent à l’exercice de déménagement.

Si maintenant le corridor est l’ouverture de mon esprit à de nouvelles idées, et que quelqu’un décide d’y passer l’immense sofa de ses théories, il se pourrait que j’en refuse éventuellement l’accès car sa façon de ménager les murs et de tourner les coins est trop brutale (l’information en place dans mon esprit, les murs de mon corridor intellectuel, doit être prise en compte si on désire y installer ses idées). Je deviens la personne à l’avant du meuble, qui refuse éventuellement l’avancée du meuble parce que la personne à l’arrière ne *pousse pas assez égal*.